# Convert TMediaPlayer->Duration to min:sec (FMX)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

I'm working with the TMediaPlayer1 control in an FMX app using C++ Builder 10.2 Version 25.0.29899.2631. The code below runs fine in Win32 and gives the expected result after loading an mp3 file that is 35 minutes, 16 seconds long.
[image]

When i run this same code targeting iOS i get the following error:

[bcciosarm64 Error] Unit1.cpp(337): use of overloaded operator '/' is ambiguous (with operand types 'Fmx::Media::TMediaTime' and 'int')

Here is my code that takes the TMediaPlayer1->Duration and converts it to min:sec,

```
UnicodeString S = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath(),"43506.mp3");
if (FileExists(S)) {
    MediaPlayer1->FileName = S;
    int sec = MediaPlayer1->Duration / 10000000;    // <-- this is problem line
    int min = sec / 60;
    sec = sec - (60 * min);
    lblEndTime->Text = IntToStr(min) + ":" + IntToStr(sec);       
}
```

How *should* i be doing that division?

**UPDATE 1:**  I fumbled around and figured out how to see the values with this code below.  When i run on Win32 i get 21169987500 for the Duration (35 min, 16 seconds) and i get 10000000 for MediaTimeScale - both correct.  When i run on iOS i get **0 for Duration** and 10000000 for MediaTimeScale.  But, if i start the audio playing (e.g. `MediaPlayer1->Play();`) first and THEN run those 2 showmessages i get the correct result for Duration.

```
    MediaPlayer1->FileName = S;  // load the mp3
    ShowMessage(IntToStr((__int64) Form1->MediaPlayer1->Media->Duration));
    ShowMessage(IntToStr((__int64) MediaTimeScale));
```

It looks like the Duration does not get set on iOS until the audio actually starts playing.  I tried a 5 second delay after setting `MediaPlayer1->Filename` but that doesn't work.  I tried a `MediaPlayer1->Play();` followed by `MediaPlayer->Stop();` but that didn't work either.

Why isn't Duration set when the FileName is assigned?  I'd like to show the Duration before the user ever starts playing the audio.

Comment: The code looks correct. Duration is type TMediaTime, which is an __int64. You could, instead of 10000000, try to use Fmx::Media::MediaTimeScale or 10000000L. In Windows, are you using the classic compiler or the new Clang compiler (BCC32 or BCC32C)? I guess that it compiles without problem with BCC32, but not with Clang (BCC32C and the macOS compiler are both Clang-based).

Comment: Thanks Rudy.  It looks like the problem is that Duration is zero until i start playing the audio.  See my "UPDATE 1" above.  Also, i am using the classic Borland compiler for Win and it uses bcciosarm64 (I guess) for iOS.

Comment: The fact that Duration is 0 is indeed a bit weird. Can't help there, sorry. But it should compile, at least with MediaTimeScale, even on iOS.

Comment: Yes, you have helped me.  i'll make a new topic on the Duration question because i can't figure it out from the help.